# Install multiple apk packages with a single apk file

Tags: apk

I've noticed that some system android apps (or packages) contain more than one apk. For example, with the following command you can see that the LG's bluetooth app contains two apks:

`adb shell pm list packages -f com.android.bluetooth`

> package:/system/app/BluetoothMidiService/BluetoothMidiService.apk=com.android.bluetoothmidiservice
>
> package:/system/app/LGBluetooth4/LGBluetooth4.apk=com.android.bluetooth

My question is, is there any installable .apk on the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) or third party stores that allows to do such a thing, either for fresh install of the app of for an upgrade?

Comment: Are they not completely different packages and apks? BluetoothMidiService -> com.android.bluetoothmidiservice and LGBluetooth4 -> com.android.bluetooth ? Or am i missing something?

Comment: @bmdixon `com.android.bluetoothmidiservice` only contains its own package, but for some reason `com.android.bluetooth` contains both, its own and bluetoothmidiservice. I want to know why this happens. It happens with other software too.

Answer (score 2):

These are two separate packages. `pm list` shows both of them because both the package names **contain** the text you searched for, `com.android.bluetooth`. It's not two APKs in one app.

There's no way to have a package consisting of multiple APK files. This doesn't make any sense. The only similar thing is when packages contain both an APK file and an OBB file containing extra data needed by the package. This feature is used primarily for games, where the assets needed by the game make it too big to fit in a single APK file.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. You have my upvote. That happens because android lists packages containing that string, doesn't have to be an exact match. So it is like using a wild card:
``com.android.bluetooth = *com.android.bluetooth*``
It's an unexpected behavior and shouldn't be happening but it is the way it works. The proper way to get the apk's for the packages is this:
`adb shell pm list packages -f `